# Pandas - How to create a one row dataframe using multiple columns of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, vectorization

I have searched how to "create a one row dataframe using multiple columns of another dataframe" all over stack overflow and other sites but I am only getting subjects like "how to merge columns" or "how to concatenate dataframes". But I have not seen how to merge column names.

I have `tsv` files that I import in python using `Pandas`. The dataframes are like this :

```
min_mz_parent | max_mz_parent | mz_bin | intensity

     405      |      415      |   999  |    750
     405      |      515      |  1000  |    5482
     405      |      515      |  1001  |    6487
                             ...
     705      |      715      |  999   |    847
     705      |      715      |  1000  |   12546
```

I have 160 files with this kind of writing. I would like to iterate over all of them and then concatenate the value of the `column 1, 2 and 3` to create the name of a new column in a new data frame and the value corresponding to this new column would be `the value of the 4th column` in the first dataframe.
At the end, I would like the final dataframe to be like this (if there is one file, and more rows if there are more files used) :

```
405_415_999 | 405_415_1000 | 405_415_1001 | ... | 705_715_999 | 705_715_1000_12546
     750    |     5482     |    6487      | ... |     847     |       12546
```

I already have a functional code. It works on small files (500ko) but it takes a LOT of time when I want to apply it to huge files : modify and then concatenate 160 tsv files of 120Mo each.

I heard that using `iterrows()`, I could lose a lot of time and I should use `vectorization` but I still do not understand how to do it with my problem.

Here is the code I have for now (I did not import the first if statement that check `args` because it does not involve my problem of dataframe :

```
tsv_list = glob.glob(args.dir + '*.tsv')

concat_tsv = pd.DataFrame()

count_file = 1

elif args.MS == 'MS2':
    for file in tsv_list:
        name = {'sample': file.split('/')[-1]}
        if 'high_J' in name['sample']:
            continue

        # Define target class name
        if name['sample'].split('_')[0:1][0] in ['UP', 'SS', 'SM', 'SH','SE','SA','PM','PA','KP','KO','EF','EA','CF']:
            target_class = [name['sample'].split('_')[0:1][0]]
        elif name['sample'].split('_')[0:1][0] in ['SAu', 'ECl']:
            target_class = name['sample'].split('_')[0:1][0]
        elif 'Blanc' in name['sample']:
            target_class = ['Blank']
        else :
            target_class = ['']
            print('Wrong name : '+name['sample'])

        print('Currently converting and adding : ' + name['sample'] + ' ### File n°' + str(count_file))

        tsv = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')

        # Create temporary pandas dataframe for each file
        tmp = pd.DataFrame(name, index=[0])
        tmp['target'] = target_class

        #  Iterate on each dataframe file and extract information
        for index, row in tsv.iterrows():
            mz = str(row['min_mz_parent']) + "_" + str(row['max_mz_parent']) + '_' + str(row['mz_bin'])
            row_df = [row['intensity']]
            tmp[mz] = row_df

        concat_tsv = pd.concat([concat_tsv, tmp], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

        count_file += 1
```

If you want more information to help me, please let me know.
I wish you a good day.

ElsaC

Comment: How many columns would you end up with? One easy performance improvement would be to add the DataFrames to a temporary data structure, and concatenate only once outside the loop.

Comment: @AMC I will have like 4,000,000 columns. I think I am already creating a temporary data structure which is tmp (a dataframe) and I concatenate it to the final one outside my iterrows function. But the problem is that inside my iterrows function, I must iterrate 4,000,000 rows (which will be turned into columns) and it takes an excessively long time :(

Comment: 4,000,000 columns seems crazy, what are you trying to do?There has to be a better way, right?

Comment: @AMC No... These data come from mass spectrometry LC-MS/MS with a cut of 0,01bin which gives a LOT of information (4,000,000 rows for each sample). I can make less cut and get files of 20Mo instead of 120Mo but it will affect the precision of my results

Comment: It's going to take forever then, no? You expect to end up with a DataFrame with 4,000,000 columns and a single row, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @AMC That is worse than that, I want a DataFrame with 4,000,000 columns and 160 rows. I know it is possible because someone in my lab did it but I don't know how because he left, I just know he used Python.